# I don't need scientific notation!

Tags: statistics

I am looking for the probability of an event occurring 3 times with a decimal probability of .065

P(A) x P(B) x P(C) = 0.065 x 0.065 x 0.065

I am getting 2.74625E-4

I need this in decimal form not scientific notation.  How do I get just a decimal?

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Kelsey What do you mean by 'probability of a decimal'? Your title isn't even a question.

Answer (score 4):

The 'E-4' is just notation for the exponent, in this case, to convert to a decimal, the decimal place needs to be moved 4 places to the left.  Any blank spaces are to be filled with zeroes.

For example:

8.45E-3  = 0.00845